# model.remove gives modelname.remove(...).exec is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I keep getting this error:

```
Mongoose: invoice.remove({ _id: 3 }, {})
TypeError: invoiceRecord.remove(...).exec is not a function
```

I tried removing the .exec but then it will not recognize my function (err,data)

Here is my function

```
var deleteInvoice = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    invoiceRecord.remove(
    ).exec(function (err, data) {  
        if (err) {
            reject(new Error('deleteInvoice ERROR : ' + err));
            return;
        }
        if (data.result.n == 0) {
            reject({code:"INVOICE_NOTFOUND", err:"This invoice could not be found: " + invoiceRecord._id});
            return;
        }
        resolve(data);
    })
})};
```

How can I do this, when my `invoiceRecord` already have the data needed to delete?

This works:

```
invoiceTable.remove (
    { _id: invoiceRecord._id }
,function(err, data) {
```

This does not:

```
    invoiceRecord.remove (
        { _id: invoiceRecord._id }
    ,function(err, data) {
```

I really do not understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is documented [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove).

Since all asynchronous Mongoose methods already return promises, your code could be rewritten to this:

```
var deleteInvoice = () => {
  return invoiceRecord.remove().then(data => {
    if (data.result.n === 0) {
      // ATTN: it's better to throw Error instances
      throw { code:"INVOICE_NOTFOUND", err:"This invoice could not be found: " + invoiceRecord._id };
    }
  }, err => {
    err.message = 'deleteInvoice ERROR : ' + err.message;
    // Re-throw error
    throw err;
  })
})};
```

Comment: Thanks Robert - Actually the mongoose example you link to also shows `product.remove(function (err, product) {` except that does not work. Thats the 3rd time in one week I find mongoose examples that are flawed.  Your example with `invoiceRecord.remove().then` worked perfectly!

Comment: @torbenrudgaard I have no idea why it wouldn't work; for me, it does, both with callbacks and with promises. I _assume_ that `invoiceRecord` is a regular Mongoose document?

Comment: Yes it is a mongoose schema. Anyway your solution worked :)

Answer (score -1):

The `remove()` method in Mongoose has been deprecated in favour of `deleteOne()` or `deleteMany()`. Therefore, it's recommended to use `deleteOne()` for deleting a single document.